# Is it necessary to have public ip or static ip to create a chat server?

Tags: android, xmpp, static-ip-address

Basically, I want to create a private chatting environment in android, in which i want to chat with my friend over internet. So my main question is that do i need to have static ip to create a messing app server (like xmpp)?

Comment: I believe yes. Even when you get a hosting server from sites like go daddy or any other service provider they provide you with static IP for that server. Static IP is necessary because all your applications instance's will be pointing to that ip which you will either hardcode in your code or map that IP to some domain name using DNS server and use that domain name in your app. Any of these cases, all the app instances will be pointing to same IP. Static IP is the ip that is dedicatedly allocated to you. So it wont change over time or when you restart your server.

Comment: It is necessary to do this.

Comment: It isn't strictly necessary.  Its preferable, but there are services like dynamic DNS.  I wouldn't use it for a  high traffic use case though.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I finally got my static ip. But some how I'm not able to configure my xmpp server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you should keep in your mind that if you want to chat over internet the  first thing you must have the address of that computer or mobile,i should say destination,That is know as IP(Internet Protocol).
So the answer of your first question is that you must have an IP address in order to chat,That is Source IP and destination IP.

Now Come to Static and Dynamic IP.If you have your personal VPN(Virtual Private Network) you can use your static IP but if do not have VPN then Its necessary to find the source and destination IP.